# How add 2 records of address for each customer in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a personal Information in 1 table and addresses in another table. Address may be 2 record (Home, Work) address. I am using Entity Framework to insert these info. Not sure how to insert 2 address for 1 personal info.

This is my method in Repository to insert personal info:

```
  public void InsertApplication(PersonalInfo personalInfo)
    {   
       creditApplicationsContext.PersonalInfos.Add(personalInfo);
    }
```

in the class of PersonalInfo I have the number of addresses so if it set to 2 means I have 2 addresses for this customer.

```
public class PersonalInfo 
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name{ get; set; }
     .....

    public int numberofaddresses{ get; set; }
  }
```

This method is insert Address in Repository:

```
  public void InsertAddress(Address address)
    {

        creditApplicationsContext.Addesses.Add(address);
    }
```

This is Address Class:

```
public class Address 
{

    public int Id { get; set; }


    public int ApplicantId { get; set; }                            


    public Applicant ApplicantTypeRef { get; set; }       


    public bool IsCurrentResidence { get; set; }


    public bool IsPreviousResidence { get; set; }


    public string StreetNumber { get; set; }


    public string StreetName { get; set; }


    public string ApartmentSuite { get; set; }
```

Comment: can you show address class?

Comment: @PavanTeja I added it to my question.

Comment: what's the problem you are facing now?Actually to save two addresses you have to call InsertAddress method in repository two times.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about this question. You say: "this is `PersonalInfo`" and then show a class called `Application`, then say, "this is `Address`", but show a class called `Residence`. Please take some time to redact the question properly

Comment: @Jcl sorry made changes. I changes the names.

Comment: @PavanTeja but we dont know if the address is 1,2 or more. in the numberofaddresses the number shows how many we have.

Comment: Why not using 1..n relation between table personnal info and adress?

Comment: @mmansouri there is 1..n relationship.

Comment: but why you need numberofaddresses? when you have data for two addresses for person you can insert them to db right?

Comment: `numberofaddresses` should not be persisted to the database, you can always retrieve this dynamically based on a `Count()`, either in memory or against the database.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you model a 1..n relationship using a collection in the principal class...

```
public class PersonalInfo 
{
    private ICollection<Address> _Addresses = new List<Address>()

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses 
    { 
       get { return _Addresses; }
       set { _Addresses = value}

    public int NumberOfAddresses
    { 
       get return Addresses.Count()
    }
}
```

...and a foreign key in the dependent class:

```
public class Address 
{
   public int PersonalInfoId {get; set;}

   public virtual PersonalInfo PersonalInfo {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can add addresses to the collection in `PersonalInfo` class...

```
personalInfo.Addresses.Add(address1);
personalInfo.Addresses.Add(address2);
```

...before adding the tree to the database

```
infoRepo.InsertApplication(personalInfo);
uow.SaveChanges();
```

...or you can set the foreign key in the address before adding it:

```
infoRepo.InsertApplication(personalInfo);
address1.PersonalInfoId = personalInfo.Id;
address2.PersonalInfoId = personalInfo.Id;
addrRepo.InsertAddress(address1);
addrRepo.InsertAddress(address2);
uow.SaveChanges();
```

References:

[Relationship conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962)